# 499 error, "Get". React, Node.js and Socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, backend

I'm having a problem with a realtime-chat using react.
I made a realtime-chat and it worked on the local host, but when I passed the chat to a real address it stopped working, not sending messages to other users connected to the chat. The following error message appears on the console:

I have two folders, one for backend and frontend
the command below is in the "server" folder, where is the backend of my chat:

[Console Eror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfYcc.png)

The "GET" was: (Server Folder)

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const cors = require("cors");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
app.use(cors());

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "https://localhost:3000/",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});
```

Then I changed it to the real address of the site:

```
  cors: {
    origin: "https://example.com.br/",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
```

On the front-end folder (Client) e have:

```
import "./App.css";
import io from "socket.io-client";
import { useState } from "react";
import Chat from "./Chat";

const socket = io.connect("https://example.com.br/");
```

It was:
 `const socket = io.connect("https://localhost:30001/");`

Both in the backend and frontend folder, in the part of "packge.json" I added  `"homepage":"https://example.com.br/"`

Not sure if the error is related to this, but I think it has something to do with it.
My goal is to make the chat send messages to everyone connected to it at the same time.
If I'm missing information or need more, please let me know.

Comment: The error message shows your production `origin` starts with `www` but the one you've configured starts with `oasi`. These must match _exactly_. Perhaps you want `origin: /whatever\.com\.br$/`

Comment: Also, use your browser's _Network_ dev tools panel to inspect the request and response. That 499 error probably comes with a message